# Azure CLI cannot conect to the Docker Daemon

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-cli, docker-daemon

I'm new with Kubernetes and Azure. I want to Deply my application and I am floowing the microsoft tutorial about kubernetes. At first I have created the resouce group and ACR instance. When I try to login in ACR console show this error:
`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

I'm using azure cli localy and I have docker running.

Comment: How do you "try to login in ACR" ?

Comment: make sure docker is running in your machine

Comment: @CSharpRocks az acr login --name myregistry

Comment: @AmitBaranes it is running. At the same time i am using a docker container locally and it is working fine

Answer (score 4):

You can  try below options to connect ACR :

run az acr login first with the --expose-token parameter. This option exposes an access token instead of logging in through the Docker CLI.

```
az acr login --name <acrName> --expose-token
```

Output displays the access token, abbreviated here:

```
{
  "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIs[...]24V7wA",
  "loginServer": "myregistry.azurecr.io"
}
```

For registry authentication, we recommend that you store the token credential in a safe location and follow recommended practices to manage docker login credentials. For example, store the token value in an environment variable:

```
TOKEN=$(az acr login --name <acrName> --expose-token --output tsv --query accessToken)
```

Then, run docker login, passing 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 as the username and using the access token as password:

```
docker login myregistry.azurecr.io --username 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 --password $TOKEN
```

you will get the below promt if you follow the above method :

```
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Login Succeeded
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems your Docker Desktop is not running. Make sure you installed the Docker for Desktop on your machine and start it if not. You should be good once you start.